# ATN ANTLR version 4 of hqlLexer is not using my Version 3 declared in POM

Tags: java, spring-boot, antlr

I m using a jar of generation library by another team that uses antlr-runtime version 3.

I lately upgraded to Spring Boot 3 and the hqlParser is causing me some troubles where the version conflict between ANTLR (ATN CLASS) is rising always that the expected is 3 but the used is 4 even if I m using the runtime version below 4.10 (which is 4)

as details here is the console log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 4 (expected 3).
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:146)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.HqlLexer.<clinit>(HqlLexer.java:1321)
    ... 127 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 4 (expected 3).
    ... 129 common frames omitted
```

my pom.xml is like below

```
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version> 
        </dependency>
<!--          <dependency> -->
<!--             <groupId>org.antlr</groupId> -->
<!--             <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId> -->
<!--             <version>4.7.2</version>  -->
<!--         </dependency> -->
```

is there a way to force spring to use version 3 of ANTLR?